# Getting XCode to include, compile and link existing (C++) codebase in XCode 4.3(.1)

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, xcode

I'm trying to 'import' my existing C++ codebase into my XCode iOS project.

Problem is, xCode won't compile (and therefore not link) my code.
This is what I've done so far:

- File > Add files to "Project".  I don't tick 'Copy files' since it's a shared codebase for multiple platforms and multiple copies of source code is not an option.
- I've added appropriate path to the "Header Search Path" project settings.  Including header files works, I can #include "stuff.h" from my Objective-C++ (.mm) file.

However, I can't find any way of actually telling XCode to compile the .cpp files?

A few points:

- I'm not looking for a way to pre compile it into a library and linking that way
- The project is a standard iOS Objective-C project.  The C++ code is called from it (that's not a problem)

**Update**

I've added the codebase **directory** to the target's "Compile Sources".  I actually have to click "Add other..." in the dialog that pops up, since I can't select the directory reference to my codebase.

When I add it, XCode asks me if I want to "Create external build system project".  I leave it ticked and the two fields with the default values "/usr/bin/make" and "$(ACTION)".  However, my codebase doesn't get compiled during the build.  Do I have to write my own Makefile ?

If I don't select "Create external build system project" then a directory reference is created under the target, but not compiled during the build and a warning is emitted:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/../codebase'
of type folder for architecture i386
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even if you don't check **Copy Files** you have to check **Add to Targets** when adding the files to the project.

[image]

If you forgot to do that, you can select the target, go to the **Build Phases** tab and add the files to **Compile Sources**.

[image]

Comment: Target (have only one) is checked under Add to Targets.

Comment: Do you have your cpp files listed in **Compile Sources**? If not did you try to add them?

Comment: We're getting there :)  If I add a single .cpp file, it gets included in the build!  However, if I select the whole directory (see my updated question), nothing gets built.  I'd rather not select all my gazillion .cpp files manually (include paths would be wrong and a added hell to have to manually add/remove files in the future)

Comment: Same problem here.  I can add one at a time but this is frustrating.  Try to add a folder and it gives me the same error you have.  Any solution?

Comment: @Halsafar It's 2014 now and it seems like there is no solution.

Comment: In Xcode 6, adding fa cpp file to Compile Sources does nothing for me, it still does not link. Even when created in Xcode.

Answer (score 9):

If you go to your Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> "+" -> "Add Others" -> (select your external source folder) -> Select: Create Group for any added folders -> Unchecked: Copy items into destination.

Now your folder will be in XCode, mimic the structure.  If you add source files to that folder in XCode the source files will be added to your external source directory just fine.  So the ease of using multiple IDEs and having to manage source linkage is solved.

The catch.  You still have to manually add files into the "Compile Sources" area.  This is rather simple.  Just click and drag your source files from the group directory in XCode right into the Compile Sources window.  So there is an extra step when you add a source file now.  Forgetting to add them to the Compile Sources window will yield unresolved symbols compile errors.

Comment: How this is considered a viable option by iOS developers blows my mind. This is fine if you have a couple files but is ridiculous when you have hundreds. I can't believe that this issue is has not been addressed as of XCode 8.

Comment: Just seeing "drag and drop" blows my mind.
This .pbxproj file blows my mind, its format is so stupid. Working with multiple developers on multiple targets makes this whole process broken with all those references. 
If you add a target to your project before merging a pull request for example, your new target won't be associated to the new "source files" that you merge in ... go figure the ones missing now.
 
Worst IDE ever, and I've used many.