# Xcode 6.2 OSX Undefined symbols for functions in other files

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm sure this is a total nube question but if someone could explain to me what's going wrong I'd be very grateful.

I create a new Cocoa App in XCode.  Call it LinkerTest. This basic app will build and run, putting a simple blank window up.

Add a new .cpp file using the C++ File template. Call it Test.cpp.  This creates Test.h too.

In Test.cpp add a simple function:

```
int TestMe(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Declare my function in Test.h

```
int TestMe(void);
```

In my AppDelegate.m (which was created automatically when I create the app) add

```
#include "Test.h"
```

In the applicationDidFinishLaunching method add:

```
printf("Test = %d\n", TestMe());
```

Now try to build.  Everything compiles ok, but it fails to link. This is the linker command:

```
Ld Build/Products/Debug/LinkerTest.app/Contents/MacOS/LinkerTest normal x86_64
cd /Users/chip/LinkerTest
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/chip/LinkerTest/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/chip/LinkerTest/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/chip/LinkerTest/Build/Intermediates/LinkerTest.build/Debug/LinkerTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinkerTest.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/chip/LinkerTest/Build/Intermediates/LinkerTest.build/Debug/LinkerTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinkerTest_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/chip/LinkerTest/Build/Products/Debug/LinkerTest.app/Contents/MacOS/LinkerTest
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_TestMe", referenced from:
       -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So any idea what I've done wrong?  Seems to me that adding the file it should link too, but it doesn't.  I know the file Test.cpp gets compiled, if I add garbage to the file, then the compiler immediately yacks on that garbage.

**EDIT:**  A couple more things.

1) Looking at this stackoverflow([Getting XCode to include, compile and link existing (C++) codebase in XCode 4.3(.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128646/getting-xcode-to-include-compile-and-link-existing-c-codebase-in-xcode-4-3)) question it seems similar but not my issue. I can confirm that my test.cpp is listed in my Compile Sources under Build Phases.

2) Looking in the LinkerTest/Build/Intermediates/LinkerTest.build/Debug/LinkerTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64 folder I find Test.o, Test.d, and Test.dia which suggests to me that Test.cpp is in fact compiling.  In that folder I also find LinkerTest.LinkFileList which when opened with a text editor shows that Test.o should be linked.

Comment: If none of those things are working, I'd encourage you to upload the source if possible to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that when you create a default Cocoa app the AppDelegate file is a .m file.  Changing that file to be AppDelegate.mm fixes the problem.  My uninformed guess is that a .m file will only handle .c files and to correctly handle .cpp files you must use .mm files.  Why xcode's default files for a default Cocoa App wouldn't be .mm files is beyond my pay grade, but there it is.